# SET IDENTITY_INSERT gives an error - IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key, identity-column

Using simple insert statement I'm trying to insert data in a table explicitly with PK keys that have an Identity property defined on itself. But when I run the statement below I'm getting a weird error message

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT MyDB.dbo.MyTable ON
```

> Msg 8107, Level 16, State 1, Line 163
>   IDENTITY_INSERT is already ON for table 'MyDB.dbo.**AnotherTable**'. Cannot perform SET operation for table 'MyDB.dbo.**MyTable** '.

Why is it complaining on `MyDB.dbo.AnotherTable` when this `Identity_Insert` is specified being specified for `MyDB.dbo.MyTable`?

Some other tables also give similar error.

Comment: This may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32861432/weird-error-msg-8107-on-sql-server-2008-r2-for-set-identity-insert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql):

> At any time, only one table in a session can have the IDENTITY_INSERT property set to ON.

If you need to insert explicit IDENTITY values into several tables, make sure you set it to OFF for the previous table before moving to the next one.

Comment: Any idea how to find out what table has the IDENTTY_INSERT ON for your session?

Comment: @MicahEpps, I don't think so. This is specific to your connection, so it can't be extracted from system tables. Your code is supposed to "know" which table had `identity_insert` enabled for it. Reconnecting, or using a different connection might be a suitable way out of it.

Comment: I set it to ON and tried to put it in a try catch block and it just still ERRORs saying its already ON and not anymore continues which doesn't MAKE SENSE at ALL. I used it on the TEMP TABLE BTW

Comment: @ajgo, check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14774939 - is that how you do the `insert`?

Comment: This was driving me nuts!  It kept saying it was on when it was off and vice versa...  Thanks for the insight.  Disconnecting and reconnecting your session gets you out of it!

Answer (score 1):

The issue was my SQL Server 2016 connection to the server. Once I disconnected and reconnected everything works well!